# Mac App Storeから導入したRealm Browser 2.1.6で新しいレコードを追加できませんでした。

Tags: ios, realm

現在Realmデータベースで簡単なTodoアプリを作っています。データを管理するためにRealm Browser 2.1.6を使っていましたが、一つの問題が発生しました。Realm Browserには(Command +)で新しいレコードを追加しましたが、このレコードはシミュレータでTodoアプリの画面に表示されませんでした。なお、Xcode 8.2とSwift 3を使っています。
このバグを経験した方がいらっしゃいますか？教えていただけませんか？

Comment: バグではないと思います。シミュレータの方で開いているファイルとブラウザが開いているファイルは本当に同じものですか？どの場所のファイルを開いているのか分かる情報を追記してもらえますか？

Comment: Kishikawa Katsumiさん、ご返信有難うございます。シミュレータの方で開いているファイルとブラウザが開いているファイルは同じだと思います。Browserで存在しているレコードを更新したら、新しい値をシミュレータにちゃんと表示されました。追加されるものだけ表示されないです。print(Realm.Configuration.defaultConfiguration.fileURL!)でdefaul.realmファイルの場所を見つけられました。宜しくお願い致します。

Comment: 問題の切り分けのためにもう少し教えてほしいのですが、例えばiPhoneアプリを終了して再度起動すると全部のデータが正しく表示されますか？
そうだとすると、iPhoneアプリの方でデータの更新する処理におかしいところがありそうですが、どういうコードで更新を検知・UIをアップデートしていますか？

Comment: Kishikawa Katsumiさん、再導入してから、解決できました。今は上手く使えるようになりました。ご時間を頂いて有難うございました。今後とも宜しくお願い致します。